# Differential Equations - Elementary Application

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a Mechanics Problem. Kindly help..

A ball is thrown upward with an initial velocity of 49 m/s. Find the velocity after 3 seconds. Find its maximum height. Compute the time it takes for the ball to return to its original point. Use g= 9.8 m/s^2 .

Using the formula: a= dv/dt

By integration, I got: v= at + vsub0

By integrating it again for the second time, wherein v= (ds/dt), I got: s= 1/2at^2 + tVsub0 + Ssub0.

I got v(3)= 19.6 m/s. Is it correct?

What will be my s at s= -1/2 gt^2 + 49t + 0 to compute for t? Is it 0? If it is 0, t will be 0 too, isn't it?

And what formula should I use to get the maximum height?
I tried solving it using physics formula H=[vi^2(sin^2theta)]/2g and I got 122.38. Which is wrong.. Correct answer is approx 5m.. How can I derive my formula using suvat equations?

Comment: I guess this should more asked in Physics section. There is no great DE in this

Comment: The maximum height answer of urs is correct.clearly it's visible that the answer is not 5 as u=49 so in this first second itself it goes to 40 mts

Answer (score 1):

A good diagram is always helpful ;) and since acceleration is constant, SUVAT can be used.

Velocity after 3 seconds:
$$ u=49, \ a=-9.8, \ t=3, \ v \ unknown:  \\ v=u+at  \therefore v \approx 19.6$$
Max. height will be attained when v=0 (no more upward velocity so ball begins to fall):
$$ u=49, \ a=-9.8, \ s \ unknown, \ v =0:  \\ v^2=u^2+2as  \therefore s \approx 122.5 $$
There are 2 ways to find the total time of flight; the first is to notice that the path is a parabola so the time taken to reach max. height is the same as the time taken to fall from max. height back to the ground (so t=10), and the second method is SUVAT again:
$$ u=49, \ a=-9.8, \ t \ unknown, \ s =0:  \\ s=ut+\frac 12 at^2  \therefore t\approx 10 \ and \ t=0$$ This SUVAT equation is a  quadratic in t so will produce two solutions for t: when the ball starts on the ground and when the ball hits the ground again. Thus t=10.

By the way, by double integrating like you did, you basically derived the s=ut+0.5at^2 equation (use Ssub0 = 0 as you're choosing the start height of the ball as zero height and use Vsub0=u=starting velocity).

Comment: SUVAT can be used, provided you know what SUVAT stands for.

Comment: SUVAT = Superfluous Usage of Venerated Articles of Treasure

Comment: What do you mean Vsub0=u? Should it be -9.8 too? I used 49 as my Vsub0 since that's the constant now in my equation.. By the way.. we were asked to look for the maximum height.. Not the time to get to the maximum height..

Comment: Vsub0 is the initial velocity, which in this case is u=49.

Comment: Fixed post to include ma. height

Answer (score 0):

Start with $v=v_o +at$ where the velocity at max height is zero and the initial velocity is 49m/s.  At the top, $0=49-9.8t$ or t=5 seconds.  5 s up, 5 s down, total hang time is 10s.  After three seconds it is still going up, so $v=49-9.8(3)=19.6 m/s$.  Its maximum height will be the distance anything falls after 5 seconds, starting from rest, so $d=v_ot+1/2 at^2=4.9(5)^2=122.5m$.